# Even Odd numbers using Nested For Next Loop VBA

Tags: vba

How do I create a For-Next loop determining whether the numbers listed are even or odd

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 6
    If i mod 2 = 0 Then
    'i is even
    Else
    'i is odd
    End If
Next i
```